# Como exportar a Excel junto con los encabezados?

Tags: c#

Con el siguiente codigo puedo exportar sin problemas un datagridview en especifico pero sin los headers. Que me hace falta para lograr esto?

```
    public void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView dataCWS)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
            fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            fichero.FileName = "ArchivoExportado";
            if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;

                aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                hoja_trabajo =
                    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                for (int i = 0; i < dataCWS.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataCWS.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if ((dataCWS.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataCWS.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                libros_trabajo.Close(true);
                aplicacion.Quit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot import because: " + ex.ToString());
        }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No sé qué es dataCWS, pero estás recorriendo sus filas y columnas. Deberías fijarte si tiene algo como un header, y exportar eso antes de empezar a exportar la grilla.

Comment: El dataCWS es el nombre que el asigne al datagridview que deseo exportar.

Comment: LO ho hecho desde un Dataset. Como puedo aplicar anchos de columna automaticos, bordes, fondos, etc al Excel exportado saludos y gracias tu codigo me ha funcionado a la perferccion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La información de los headers está en la colección de columnas del `DataGridView`, así que puedes hacer algo así justo después de cargar el `Worksheet`:

```
hoja_trabajo = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

for (int i = 0; i < dataCWS.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, i + 1] = dataCWS.Columns[i].HeaderText;
}
```

Ahora ten en cuenta que el contenido de las celdas comenzará a partir de la línea 2 y no de la 1.

Comment: Me ayudo lo que pusiste de codigo dentro del for pero curiosamente no me salen todos los headers jaja. de las 15 columnas que tiene el datagrid, en la exportacion solo me faltan las ultimos 4 headers.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cambiar tu ciclo de la siguiente manera:

```
int columnaIndice = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataCWS.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataCWS.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(columnaIndice = 1)
                    {
                        var titulo = dataCWS.Columns[j].HeaderText;

                        // Lo asignas
                    }

                    if ((dataCWS.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataCWS.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }

                    columnaIndice++;
                }

                columnaIndice = 1;
            }
```

Comment: Intente con este ciclo y sigue igual, no consigo exportar los headers. Que podra ser?

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en tus variables si lo corres paso a paso solo veras que sobre escribes  los encabezados si pones

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, i] = this.dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

                    }
```

entes lo que tienes que hacer para corregirlo es esto:

```
  int valorFila = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, i] = this.dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

                    }
                    valorFila = valorFila + 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataCWS.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataCWS.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if ((dataCWS.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                            {

                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[valorFila+1, j + 1] = dataCWS.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();


                            }
                        }
                        valorFila++;
                    }
```

y listo te muestra todos los valores con encabezador